# Looking for solution to show div random at 1 per 100 rate without creating other divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I'm looking for a solution to show only 1 div with rate 1/100. Now I'm using this javascript:

```
var random = Math.floor(Math.random() * $('.item').length);
$('.item').hide().eq(random).show();
```

It solves my problem if I create 100 div's with `.item` class but it makes a huge mess in my code.

Comment: your quection is unclear, please give us more details

Comment: I have a div which I want to show randomly only one time per 100 requests. Now I'm using 99 empty div(s) and 1 with content, but it makes code huge. So I'm looking for a solution to have only one div which will be shown randomly at rate 1/100. I hope now it's clear.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I asume you want to show a div randomly when you refresh the page.

Javascrip (jquery):

```
$(document).ready(function(e) {

    var randomNum = Math.floor(Math.random() * 100) + 1 ;
    $(".item_" + randomNum).show();

});
```

HTML:

```
<div class="item_1" style="display:none;">This div show randomly</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/12f9hpny/

When random number is 1 this div will show.
Hope this will help.

Comment: Thank you! Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you just do:

```
// Random number between 1 and 100
var random = (Math.random() * 100) + 1;
// Gets the element to show
var element = $('.item');
// Show the element only if random == 1
if(random == 1) element.show();
```

Comment: Because I'm not that skilled in javascript. Can you tell me where did I make mistake? http://jsfiddle.net/hrAHT/383/

Comment: Because you are using pure JS on your fiddle but this solution uses jQuery. For a pure JS solution, check this: http://jsfiddle.net/hrAHT/392/